# Trying to get code to output multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, csv, writer

I am importing a data set and trying to output some text analysis. However, I can only get it to output the last column of data. Where do I put the csv.writer in order to get all the lines of code in?

```
from __future__ import division
import csv
import re
from string import punctuation

faithwords = ['church', 'faith', 'faith']

with open('dataset.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    for row in data:

        faithcounter = 0 

        row3 = row[3]
        row3 = row3.lower().replace('  ', ' ')
        row4 = row[4]
        row4 = row4.lower().replace('  ', ' ')

        for p in list(punctuation):
            row3 = row3.replace(p, '')
            row4 = row4.replace(p, '')

        essay1= re.split(' ', row3)
        essay2= re.split(' ', row4)

        essay1len = len(essay1)
        essay2len = len(essay2)

        num_of_rows = len(row)

        for word in essay1:
            if word in faithwords:
                faithcounter = faithcounter + 1  

        for word in essay2:
            if word in faithwords:
                faithcounter = faithcounter + 1            

        totallen = (essay2len + essay1len)

        row.append(essay1len)
        row.append(essay2len)
        row.append(totallen)
        row.append(faithcounter)        
        row.append(faithcounter / totallen)

        output = zip(row)

writer = csv.writer(open('csvoutput.csv', 'wb'))
writer.writerows(output)
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with `zip(row)` at the end of your loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
output=zip(row)
```

I'm not sure why you are doing `zip`, but I do know that your are overwriting `output` on each iteration.

I recommend that you create your csv writer before your loop.  Then, as the last statement in your loop, do:

```
writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing `output=zip(row)` and replace it with `writer.write(row)`

Remove `writer.writerows(output)` and put `writer = csv.writer(open('csvoutput.csv', 'wb'))`
 above your loop.